# Joining letters using lambdas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a DataFrame that contains a column with lists of letters:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':      [1, 2, 3, 4, 10], 
                   'date':    [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                   'str':     [["a", "b"],["b", "c"],["c", "d"],["d", "e"],["e", "f"]]})
```

I want to join these letters to a single word. This is the solution I came up with:

```
df.str.apply(lambda w: " ".join( [w for w in w]))
```

This seems to work as intended, but I'm unsure of how "correct" it is as I am new to Python and lambdas. Normally when we write loops we use a different index for the variable we loop with and the variable being looped over, but here they are the same.

Comment: Your question has a broad scope. But one hint: If it's a `oneshot` solution it is okay. But typically, you want functions with proper names instead of lambdas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `apply` `join`

```
df.str.apply(' '.join)
Out[162]: 
0    a b
1    b c
2    c d
3    d e
4    e f
Name: str, dtype: object
```

Also without apply

```
df['str'].str.join(sep=' ')
Out[163]: 
0    a b
1    b c
2    c d
3    d e
4    e f
Name: str, dtype: object
```

Comment: What if I want to make all letters uppercase before joining or apply some function to them? Then I guess lambdas are necessary?

Comment: @N08 nope `df['str'].str.join(sep=' ').str.upper()`

Comment: Thanks. Say I have a list of words I want to make sure `df['str']` does not contain. Then I would use a lambda like `df.str.apply(lambda w: " ".join( [w for w in w if w not in ["a", "b"]))`. Is this optimal?

Comment: @N08  `df['str'].str.join(sep=' ').replace({'a':'','b':''},regex=True)`

Comment: Thanks, that's nice. Say my list of unwanted words is so long that I can't (wont) write it out explicitly as in your example - then what (?)

Comment: @N08 `df['str'].str.join(sep=' ').replace(dict(zip(l,['']*len(l))),regex=True)`, l here is your list

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `apply` as:

```
`df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x['str']), axis = 1)`
```